# How would I be able to solve this difficult Hidato?

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

So I was doing Hidato puzzles on the official Hidato site when I came across this puzzle that I am having trouble solving, and while I have been able to solve it partly, I don't think that I'm going to be able to solve it fully without at least a hint.

Would somebody be able to give me a hint on what to do next?

What I have done so far:

[image]

Puzzle id: `h-6-003988`

<sub>I hate hexagonal Hidato</sub>

Comment: I'll post a proper answer when I have time, but I can immediately see a problem. You have no space for 87

Comment: @fljx Whoops must have missed that somehow tbh

Comment: Errors aside, you can get ahead by connectivity: no matter how the 20 connects to the 26, it creates a wall of numbers smaller than 58. That wall creates a dead end pocket with a single hex wide entrance, so 59 cannot be below 58 (or the number snake gets trapped), and the same goes for 57 (the snake cannot exit the dead end pocket without entering it first). That should allow you to fill in (at least most of) the bottom right.

Comment: @Bass Yeah, thanks for saying! I will definitely fill those in!

Comment: I think the problem is that you seem to place numbers without being sure it is the correct position.  For instance the sequence from 107 to 113 could be moved up one cell, but you have chosen one option without knowing whether it is correct.

Comment: How do I use the puzzle id to access the puzzle? (What is the "official Hidato site"?

Comment: @fljx Oh, sorry about that, the official site is hidato.com, I should have mentioned that. To use the puzzle id, you need to start a 5-star difficulty Hidato puzzle and then click on the txt box next to "Enter puzzle #" in the top right and then enter the id (in this case `h-6-003988`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things.

> Where would you put the 34?

> 58 must link to 54 and 68.  This leaves only one option for the cell right of 33.  And 33 must find a way to 26.